# Customize pie chart slice in DOJO

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I am using Dojo 1.6 to generate dynamic Chart. Here i need to put the Numeric percentage(%) outside the respective slice of chart, as i got the following pie chart.
[image]

code for the above chart..

```
 dojo.xhrPost({
            url :"/ritl/chart/getModelPieDataForAll.htm",
            handleAs : "json",
            load : function(response, ioargs) {
             require([
            "dojox/charting/Chart",
            "dojox/charting/themes/MiamiNice",
            "dojox/charting/plot2d/Pie",
            "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
            "dojox/charting/action2d/MoveSlice",
            "dojo/colors",
            "dojox/charting/plot2d/Markers",
            "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
            "dojo/domReady!" ], 
            function(Chart, theme, Pie, Tooltip, MoveSlice,Legend) {
                var chart = new Chart("chartForModel",{
                    title: "Model Pie Chart",
                    titlePos: "bottom",
                    titleGap: 25,
                    titleFont: "normal normal normal 15pt Arial",
                    titleFontColor: "black"
                });
            chart.setTheme(dojox.charting.themes.MiamiNice);
            chart.addPlot("default", {
                    type : Pie, 
                    markers : true, 
                    radius : 100
                });
            chart.addAxis("x");
            chart.addAxis("y", {min : 100, max : 10000, vertical : true, fixLower : "major", fixUpper : "major"});
            chart.addSeries("Sales Product - 2013", response.data);
            chart.render();
            new dojox.charting.widget.Legend({
                chart : chart,
                horizontal : true
              }, "legend1");
            });
        },
    error : function(response, ioargs) {console.log("Inside Handle Error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add labelOffset: to chart.addPlot.

For example `chart.addPlot("default", {
                    type : Pie, 
                    markers : true, labelOffset: -17, radius : 100
                });`